# Default script max runtime for browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

What's the default script running time for IE,Chrome,firefox? Any way to increase the script runtime by javascript code

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has a setting to disable the 'too long script`

IE isn't a matter of time, but the number of instructions.  (At least IE 6 and 7)

Chrome I don't know.

Opera doesn't block scripts -- it works automagically.

The solution is to break up your script so that looks run in some kind of `window.setTimeout` method over each iteration or so.

If you post the method that is blocking too long, we might be able to help with it.